# Error in parametric equation on my opengl/glut.h code

Tags: c++, opengl

This is the question:

> The parametric equation on below sets a curve with t ∈ R:
>
> x(t) = sin(t) + 1/2 sin(5t) + 1/4 cos(2,3t)
>
> y(t) = cos(t) + 1/2 cos(5t) + 1/4 sin(2,3t)
>
> Use GL_LINE_STRIP to do a white curve and GL_POINTS to do the last
>   calculated point in red. The drawn should be drawing in real time, it
>   means, at every moment, a new point will be calculates and with that,
>   we will see the curve being constructed, as the picture below. Use the
>   callback timer with 10 millisecond as waiting time. Clue: use ortho
>   range from -2.0 to 2.0 in x and y.
>
> IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6tiC.png

My code is almost done, but with two issues.

The first one is: The image is not in curve! It's creating straight lines between the calculated points. I don't know if a did the formula wrong, if it's missing some parenthesis in somewhere or something like that.

The second one is: The red point is being created, but the old one is still there. I need do something in order to remove the old ones, but this is not a big problem, the first one is crazing me out.

This is my code:
PS: The comments are in portuguese as it is my first language.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void display(void);
void init(void);
void reshape (int w, int h); 
void desenhaEixos();
void projecao(void);
void desenhaCurvaLinha(float centerX, float centerY);
void timer (int i);
void desenhaPonto(float centerX, float centerY);

float minX = -2; //Parâmetros do glOrtho
float maxX = 2;
float minY = -2;
float maxY = 2;
float minZ = -1;
float maxZ = 1;

int k = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //Escopo de criação de janela
    glutInit(&argc, argv);//Avisa que será criada uma janela
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500); //Diz o tamanho da janela
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10); //Diz onde a janela vai abrir na tela, em pixel
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH); //Prepara o sistema para a janela a ser criada, é extremamente importante

    glutCreateWindow("FreeGLUT Shapes");//Cria a janela

    //Escopo de registro de callbacks
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);   

    //glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutTimerFunc(1000/*valor em milesegundos*/, timer, 1);

    //Demais
    init();
    glutMainLoop();//Fica esperando a ação do usuário



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



void display(void){
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);//Limpando o buffer de cor

     desenhaCurvaLinha(1, 1);
     desenhaPonto(1, 1);

     glutSwapBuffers();
     }



void init(void){

     glClearColor(0,0,0,0);//Escolhe a cor do fundo da janela, nesse caso, preto
}



void desenhaEixos(){

     //glLineWidth(3); //Caso queira mudar a espessura da linha

     glBegin(GL_LINES); //Indica que vou desenhar linhas

          glColor3f(1,0,0); // Vermelho
          glVertex3f(minX, 0, 0); //Estamos escrevendo o eixo X na tela
          glVertex3f(maxX, 0, 0);// Fui do mínimo até o máximo, da esquerda da tela até a direita

          glColor3f(0,1,0); //Verde
          glVertex3f( 0, minY, 0);
          glVertex3f( 0, maxY, 0);

          glColor3f(0,0,1); //Azul
          glVertex3f( 0, 0, minZ);
          glVertex3f( 0, 0, maxZ);

     glEnd();   
}



void desenhaCurvaLinha(float centerX, float centerY){
     float x, y;
     int t;
     glColor3f(1,1,1);
     glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
          for(t=0;t<=k;t++){ 
               x = sin(t) + 0.5 * sin (5 * t) + 0.25 * cos (2.3*t);
               y = cos(t) + 0.5 * cos (5 * t) + 0.25 * sin (2.3*t);
               glVertex2f(x, y);      
          }  
     glEnd();
}

void desenhaPonto(float centerX, float centerY){
     float x, y;
     int t;
     glPointSize(5);
     glColor3f(1,0,0);
     glBegin(GL_POINTS);
          for(t=0;t<=k;t++){ 
               x = sin(t) + 0.5 * sin (5 * t) + 0.25 * cos (2.3*t);
               y = cos(t) + 0.5 * cos (5 * t) + 0.25 * sin (2.3*t);
               glVertex2f(x, y);      
          }  
     glEnd();
}



void reshape (int w, int h){
     glViewport(0,0,w,h); //linha protocolo
     projecao();
}



void projecao(void){

     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     glOrtho(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ); // Diz agora, que o X da minha janela começa no -10 e termina no 10, o y também.
     glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
     glLoadIdentity();

}



void timer (int i){


      k++;    
      glutPostRedisplay();
      glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get straight lines between points because you're drawing straight lines between points (and that's all you can do on a pixel display).

The `t` in the formula is continuous, t ∈ R.
Your `t` isn't, and can't be because you're using a digital computer.

For a smoother "curve", use smaller steps than 1 between the points on the line.

You're also drawing many points because you're using a loop that draws all the points on your curve (I suspect copy-and-paste was involved).

Remove the loop in `desenhaPonto` and only draw the last point, where `t = k`:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    x = sin(k) + 0.5 * sin (5 * k) + 0.25 * cos (2.3*k);
    y = cos(k) + 0.5 * cos (5 * k) + 0.25 * sin (2.3*k);
    glVertex2f(x, y);      
glEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you very much molbdnilo, yes, it was an copy-and-paste ¬¬ Now, the only issue is that the line is not drawing... But you helped me a lot!

Comment: Now it's done, I had removed both loop, not only in desenhaPonto ¬¬ Thanks very much man